# *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm having this exception that is not being caught, even is in a handling exception (`@try{}@catch{}`), it is probably something very easy but I can't see it at the moment. The exception says  **'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'** I believe a parameter is being pass `nil` but I don't see it:

```
-(void) theProblemMethod
{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        @try {
                [[self topViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: ^{

                     UIViewController * rootViewControler = nil;
                    if ((rootViewControler = (UIViewController *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController))
                     {
                         if([self topViewController])
                             [(UINavigationController *)[self topViewController].navigationController popToViewController:rootViewControler animated:YES];
                         if ((rootViewControler = (UIViewController *) [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController].presentedViewController)) {
                             [rootViewControler dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:
                              ^{
                                  //do something here
                              }];
                         }
                     }
                 }];

        } @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"There is a problem at [myClass theProblemMethod]  Exception: %@, reason: %@",  [exception name], [exception reason]);
        } @finally {}
     });
}
```

Does anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens when the popped view controller is nil, or the popped view controller is not in the navigation view controller stack. Check both before popping.

```
UIViewController *poppedVC = ...
UINavigationController *nc = ...
if (poppedVC && [nc.viewControllers containsObject:poppedVC]) {
    [nc popViewControllerAnimated:poppedVC];
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution but and didn't work because the if condition does not work for this case because the rootViewControler ins't a child of topViewController.navigationController.

Answer (score 0):

**I found the problem!** I just found that the problem pointed to be at the line:

```
[(UINavigationController *)[self topViewController].navigationController popToViewController:rootViewControler animated:YES];
```

My code was trying to access the property **navigationController** after dismiss **topViewController** view (its parent).

The solution for this was store the navigationController**strong text** in a temporal variable before dismiss **topViewController** after the `@try`:

```
UINavigationController * aNavigationController = (UINavigationController *)[[self topViewController] navigationController];
```

Finally :

```
 -(void) theProblemMethod
    {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            @try {
                    UINavigationController * aNavigationController = (UINavigationController *)[[self topViewController] navigationController];
                    [[self topViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: ^{

                         UIViewController * rootViewControler = nil;
                        if ((rootViewControler = (UIViewController *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController))
                         {
                                 [(UINavigationController *)[self topViewController].navigationController popToViewController:rootViewControler animated:YES];
                             if ((rootViewControler = (UIViewController *) [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController].presentedViewController)) {
                                 [rootViewControler dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:
                                  ^{
                                      //do something here
                                  }];
                             }
                         }
                     }];

            } @catch (NSException *exception) {
                NSLog(@"There is a problem at [myClass theProblemMethod]  Exception: %@, reason: %@",  [exception name], [exception reason]);
            } @finally {}
         });
    }
```

Basically I was removing **A** and trying at the same time to invoke its child **A.child** inside **A** right after **A** was removed.